# Hot swap in Ubuntu Server not working

Tags: sata, ubuntu-server, hotswapping

I am running Ubuntu Server 10.04 (lucid lynx), and I just purchased a hot-swap compatible hdd bay and installed it. When I insert a hot-swappable SATA drive, the drive does not show up after running `ls /dev/sd?`. If I reboot the server, then after it comes back up the drive appears. I have checked /var/log/messages and nothing shows up when I insert the drive, only after rebooting.

I have tried the following:

```
$ sudo echo "0 0 0" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host4/scan
$ sudo partprobe`
$ sudo udevadm trigger
```

Every answer I've found searching Google was one of the things I listed in "I have tried..." and I don't really know what to do at this point. Does anyone know why this occurring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This turned out to be a face-palm moment for me. I was sure I had AHCI turned on in the BIOS settings. Looks like I was wrong. After I turned on AHCI, hot swapping worked like a charm!